# elegant way to iterate & compare in Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Spark DataFrame with 2 columns: `C1:Seq[Any]` and `C2:Double`. I want to

1. Sort by length of `C1`.
2. For each element `c1` in `C1`, compare with every other element in `C1` that is longer than `c1`.

   2.1 If `c1` is contained in an another element `cx`, then compare `c2` with `c2x`.

   2.2 If `c2` > `c2x`, then filter out `(c1x, c2x)`.

Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

Sample Input:

```
C1 C2
ab 1.0
abc 0.5
```

Expected output:

```
C1 C2
ab 1.0
```

Contain = subset. e.g. ab is contained in abc.

Comment: first of all share what you;ve tried so far. Then share some input samples and expected result. The last thing for you to do is clarify the point `If c1 is contained in an another element cx, then compare c2 with c2x`

Answer (score -1):

> > I have a Spark DataFrame with 2 columns: C1:Seq[Any] and C2:Double

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(("ab", 1.0), ("abc", 0.5)))
```

> > 1. Sort by length of `C1`.

```
val rddSorted = rdd.sortBy(_._1.length).collect().distinct
```

> > 2. For each element `c1` in `C1`, compare with every other element in `C1` that is longer than `c1`.
> >     
> >        2.1 If `c1` is contained in an another element `cx`, then compare `c2` with `c2x`.
> >        2.2 If `c2` > `c2x`, then filter out `(c1x, c2x)`.

```
val result = for(
        (x, y) <- rddSorted;
        (a, b) <- rddSorted.dropWhile{case(c,d) => c == x && d == y};
        if(a.contains(x) && a.length > x.length && y > b)
      )yield (x, y)
```

Thats all. You should get what you are looking for

Comment: didn't the answer helped you that you downvoted. if it didn't then I should be deleting it